# Windows Xp (Tiny XP vs Win Xp Pro Sp3) Different Window Sizes

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Very strange question but I have some legacy code that interacts with another application by checking exact pixel positions. The windows need to be exactly the same size.

I am trying to deploy the code on TinyXp to lower the footprint or the OS but the window size is coming out 2 pixels thinner than on regular windows sp3 64bit. I've copied over the theme and font rendering stuff but have no idea what the deal is.

Incidentally, this window can't be resized horizontally.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From one Windows installtion to another, many things can change. Maybe you can dump out the result of calls to the windows [GetSystemMetrics Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385%28VS.85%29.aspx) on the two different machines.

DPI Settings also have a great influence on Windows look. This article can be interesting to check: [Writing High-DPI Win32 Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464660%28VS.85%29.aspx)